# Kotlin - Coroutines not behaving as expected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This question is linked to one of my previous questions: [Kotlin - Coroutines with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207305/kotlin-coroutines-with-loops).

So, this is my current implementation:

```
fun propagate() = runBlocking {
    logger.info("Propagating objectives...")
    val variablesWithSetObjectives: List<ObjectivePropagationMapping> =
        variables.filter { it.variable.objective != Objective.NONE }
    variablesWithSetObjectives.forEach { variableWithSetObjective ->
        logger.debug("Propagating objective ${variableWithSetObjective.variable.objective} from variable ${variableWithSetObjective.variable.name}")
        val job: Job = launch {
            propagate(variableWithSetObjective, variableWithSetObjective.variable.objective, this, variableWithSetObjective)
        }
        job.join()
        traversedVariableNames.clear()
    }
    logger.info("Done")
}

private tailrec fun propagate(currentVariable: ObjectivePropagationMapping, objectiveToPropagate: Objective, coroutineScope: CoroutineScope, startFromVariable: ObjectivePropagationMapping? = null) {
    if (traversedVariableNames.contains(currentVariable.variable.name)) {
        logger.debug("Detected loopback condition, stopping propagation to prevent loop")
        return
    }
    traversedVariableNames.add(currentVariable.variable.name)
    val objectiveToPropagateNext: Objective =
        if (startFromVariable != currentVariable) {
            logger.debug("Propagating objective $objectiveToPropagate to variable ${currentVariable.variable.name}")
            computeNewObjectiveForVariable(currentVariable, objectiveToPropagate)
        }
        else startFromVariable.variable.objective
    logger.debug("Choosing variable to propagate to next")
    val variablesToPropagateToNext: List<ObjectivePropagationMapping> =
        causalLinks
            .filter { it.toVariable.name == currentVariable.variable.name }
            .map { causalLink -> variables.first { it.variable.name == causalLink.fromVariable.name } }
    if (variablesToPropagateToNext.isEmpty()) {
        logger.debug("Detected end of path, stopping propagation...")
        return
    }
    val variableToPropagateToNext: ObjectivePropagationMapping = variablesToPropagateToNext.random()
    logger.debug("Chose variable ${variableToPropagateToNext.variable.name} to propagate to next")
    if (variablesToPropagateToNext.size > 1) {
        logger.debug("Detected split condition")
        variablesToPropagateToNext.filter { it != variableToPropagateToNext }.forEach {
            logger.debug("Launching child thread for split variable ${it.variable.name}")
            coroutineScope.launch {
                propagate(it, objectiveToPropagateNext, this)
            }
        }
    }
    propagate(variableToPropagateToNext, objectiveToPropagateNext, coroutineScope)
}
```

I'm currently running the algorithm on the following variable topology (Note that the algorithm follows arrows coming to a variable, but not arrows leaving from a variable):
[image: Variable topology]

Currently I am getting the following debug print result: https://pastebin.com/ya2tmc6s.

As you can see, even though I launch coroutines they don't begin executing until the main propagate recursive function has finished  exploring a complete path.

I would want the launched coroutines to start executing immediately instead...

Comment: I don't understand 100% what the function is trying to do, but your comment "coroutines (...) don't begin executing until the main propagate recursive function has finished (...)" and the code lines: 7-10 look weird. You `launch` a coroutine and `join` immediately after - this makes no sence. Maybe you want to launch with `onEach( launch { } )` and afterwards (!) join with `.forEach { it.join() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, all the coroutines you start within `runBlocking` will run on the same thread.

If you want to enable multithreading, you can just change that to `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default)`.   I'm just going to assume that all that code is thread-safe.

If you don't really want to enable multithreading, then you really shouldn't care what order the coroutines run in.